# javascript jquery why is my formatted date substracting 1 one day from the actual value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a date that is stored in my sql server database as 2013-06-12 00:00:00.0000000.  But when I retrieve it with $.getJSON and then format it, the date is displayed as jun 11 2013. As a check, I displayed the value with out any formatting to make sure the correct value would render, in which it did. Can anybody give me a clue as to why a day is being subtracted from the original date when formatted. Here is the jquery code that i am using:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('M dd yy', new Date(val.DeliveryDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are stored as GMT in MySql. When you grab them through your getJSON call, the date is converted to your local time zone. It's already tomorrow in England relative to us (8pm).

Comment: What indicates that the date is stored as GMT or is this just the default. Also I wasn't clear before, but it's Microsoft SQL server and not MySql if that makes any difference.  I've formatted many dates before via c#/razor syntax and never had this problem.  This is my first time with javascript/jquery. So how would I go about correcting this issue.

Comment: Too many variables are at play here. I would want to see more code - how you retrieve data on server side, send it to client, client side call, and finally JSON object that is coming back from the server. When you debug, before sending data to client, what do you see as date value? There are a lot of things you could take a loot at. Please share your findings.